# Как добавить элемент в лист листов, чтобы сделать список смежности для графа?

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    list <int> :: iterator it;
    list<list<int>> Graph[1000];
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int v;
        cin >> v;
        Graph[i].insert(it, v);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вот приложили Вы код. Зачем? Он работает? Не работает? Если не работает, то как именно? Выдаёт ошибку? Не компилится? Не делает то, что Вы от него хотите? Внесите больше подробностей.

Comment: А по коду вот что: во-первых, `list<list<int>> Graph[1000];` это не *лист листов*, а тысяча *листов листов*. Во-вторых, чтобы добавить элемент в список списков (так называются *листы* по-русски), следует сначала создать список, заполнить его элементами, а потом уже заполненный добавить в список списков. Либо сразу сделать список пустых списков с помощью `list<list<int>> Graph(1000);`, а потом проходить в цикле по элементам и заполнять. А ещё для добавления в конец списка есть удобный метод `push_back`.

Comment: И ещё, судя по Вашему коду, у Вас получается, что в списке списков будет много маленьких списков по одному элементу. Не пойму, зачем так и чего Вы этим хотели добиться.